# WiFi AP's have no internet connectivity after seting up IPTABLES

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, dhcp, netplan

I have set up an Ubuntu 20.04 SERVER to act as a Gateway/Router.
Now that the gateway is functioning, I now no longer have WiFi access via several AP's in my house.
I am able to connect to the AP's, I just do not have internet access.
It appears that DHCP (dnsmasq) HAS handed out an IP address. I just don't have internet connectivity.
Is there something I am missing in my IPTABLES rules?

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Network Address Translation (NAT)
-A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0f0 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

#################
# Service rules #
#################

# Basic Global Accept Rules
# Loopback
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# ICMP
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f0 -p icmp -j DROP
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Traceroute
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33523 -j DROP

# Established
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# DNS - accept from LAN
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# SSH - accept from LAN
-A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Deal with AP's
#-A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

# DHCP client requests - accept from LAN
-A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -p udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT

# Drop all other input traffic
-A INPUT -j DROP

####################
# Forwarding rules #
####################

# Forward packets along established/related connections
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Forward from LAN to WAN
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0f1 -o enp1s0f0 -j ACCEPT

# Drop all other forwarded traffic
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

Comment: Are your WiFi devices setup as simple switches instead of routers? I think yes, if your WiFi clients are getting DHCP addresses from your server, but please confirm. I use static IP addresses for my WiFi AP's, outside of my dynamic address pool, but on the same sub-net as everything else.

Comment: @DougSmythies, yes. these are older LinkSys WRT54GL WiFi Router/AP's running Tomato. The routing/DHCP function is disabled and they are only acting as (basically) as AP's.
I can connect to the AP via a static IP address in a web browser (to manage) and I am connected with my phone, I just have no internet access via WiFi on my phone.

Comment: @DougSmythies The basic setup: Internet --> CableModem --> Gateway/Router --> 24PortSwitch --> WiFiAP <-- WiFi-Signals --> CellPhone.  The Cell IS getting an IP from the GateWay/Router and is connecting to the WiFiAP. There is just no internet connectivity. Also from the cell I am able to http into the AP and manage it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to create an outgoing internet connection from your clients. At the outset iptables doesn't know to deal with the packet, which would thereafter traverse the FORWARD chain.

In your INPUT chain, perhaps before your port 67,68 stuff, add this line:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp1s0f1 -s $INTNET -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT
```

where:
$INTNET is your internal network definition,
i.e. INTNET="192.168.111.0/24" in my case.
$UNIVERSE is anything,
i.e. UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

Also change this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

to this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp1s0f0 -s $UNIVERSE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Doug, As soon as I put the "-i enp1sof1" part in, it will not work. As soon as I take that part out, the phone connects as I describe in my answer above.
Additionally, it is really slow to connect, sometimes, Android times out "waiting", then after it announces it has no internet connectivity, it eventually connects.
I did add your other suggestion in.

Comment: @ScottVinzant : well, I don't have time to go into it. Use logging and tcpdump like we did the other day to narrow it down. By the way, your "lo" rule should be more generic, i.e. any source or any destination is O.K. for "lo".

Answer (score 0):

@DougSmythies
Building on your answer, I removed the "-i enp1s0f1" portion and it seems to work.
I also found that I can specify individual IP addresses i.e:
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.84 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`
This would allow me control over individual devices on the LAN.
I'm not sure why having the LAN interface included caused it to balk, but once I removed it, it worked.

Comment: you want to specify interfaces for this stuff. See edit in a minute.